# Artin Proposition 2.5.3

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, induction

This is a rather obvious fact that I know how to prove, but want to be sure that I have proper proof etiquette. The statement is:

> If $\varphi: G \to G'$ is a group homomorphism and $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in G$, then $\varphi(a_1, \ldots, a_k) = \varphi(a_1) \cdots \varphi(a_k)$.

This can be proved fairly easily by induction on $k$.

> We induct on $k$. The $k = 1$ is clear, and the $k =2$ case follows from the definition of a group homomorphism. Suppose $\varphi(a_1 \cdots a_k) = \varphi(a_1) \cdots \varphi(a_k)$ for some $k \geq 1$. We then have
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi\left(a_1 \cdots a_k  a_{k+1}\right) = \varphi\left((a_1 \cdots a_k) a_{k+1}\right) = \varphi(a_1 \cdots a_k) \varphi(a_{k+1}) = \varphi(a_1) \cdots \varphi(a_k) \varphi(a_{k+1}),
> \end{align*}
> which closes the induction.

My question is: should I suppose the result holds for $k \geq 2$? Otherwise, when I write $\varphi(a_1 \cdots a_k a_{k+1})$, it seems that I'm referring to three distinct elements $a_1, a_k, a_{k+1}$ when in fact, if $k = 1$, we have $a_1 = a_k$. I could use product notation to make this transition somewhat more seamless, but then there's some added confusion, as that in s some sense "assumes" commutativity.

Comment: I guess you meant $\varphi(a_1 \ldots a_k) = \dots$, not $\varphi(a_1, \ldots, a_k) =\dots$.

Comment: Yes, thank you for catching this.

Comment: You seem to be questioning standard informal notation, which is a reasonable thing to do. If you want to be more formal, you could provide a formal inductive definition for $a_1 \cdots a_k$, for integers $k \ge 1$. Define it to be $a_1$ if $k=1$ and $(a_1 \cdots a_{k-1})a_k$ for $k > 1$. You could use the notation $\prod_{i=1}^k a_k$ (which doesn't necessarily imply commutativity), but then you would also need to define it first!

Answer (score 1):

How does strong induction work? You want to prove that $P(k)$ is true for all $k \geq 1$. This consists in two steps:

1. showing that $P(1)$ is true.
2. showing that for all $k \geq 1$, $(P(1) \wedge \cdots \wedge P(k)) \implies P(k+1)$.

The predicate $P(k)$ here is "for all $a_1,\ldots, a_k \in G$, $\varphi(a_1\cdots a_k) = \varphi(a_1)\cdots \varphi(a_k)$". So for step $1$, we must take $a_1 \in G$ and show that $\varphi(a_1)$ (the left side) equals $\varphi(a_1)$ (the right side). Nothing to do.

For step $2$, fix $k \geq 1$, assume that $P(1)$ through $P(k)$ are all true, and show that $P(k+1)$ is true. As you observe, there are two cases to look at. If $k=1$, we only assume that $P(1)$ is true, and have to prove that $P(2)$ is true. Of course, $P(1)$ alone is completely useless, but $P(2)$ being true is saying that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, which was our assumption. This concludes this case. If $k \geq 2$, take $a_1,\ldots, a_{k+1} \in G$, and proceed as $$\varphi(a_1\ldots a_{k+1}) = \varphi((a_1\cdots a_k)a_{k+1}) \stackrel{P(2)}{=} \varphi(a_1\ldots a_k)\varphi(a_{k+1}) \stackrel{P(k)}{=} \varphi(a_1)\cdots \varphi(a_{k+1}).$$

Comment: The strong induction argument makes sense to me, but what about "regular" induction? Is an induction hypothesis of assuming the result for $k \geq 1$ sufficient, or do I need the $k \geq 2$ hypothesis?

Comment: For regular induction you might as well assume that $k \geq 2$. After all, you have already established the $k=1$ case in the base of the induction.

Comment: Is it incorrect not to, however, since I referred to three different indexed quantities? This is what I am still not fully certain about, even though a workaround is surely taking $k \geq 2$.